# Sending arguments from the command line in java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm relatively new to java and would like to generate a program that reads text from pdf based on a command line argument I provide.  In this example, I'd like to pass the file document.pdf (in the same directory as my jar file). I have also tried sending files from my desktop using /home/myname/Desktop/document.pdf (to see if this is a relative / absolute path issue).  I continue to get a file not found error.  I thought with the following invocation I am sending the files path as args[0] to the program ..

```
java -jar fileRead.jar fileRead document.pdf

---or--- 

java -jar filereadjar fileRead /home/myname/Desktop/document.pdf
```

if i replace `filesInputStream(args[0]);` with `filesInputStream("/home/myname/Desktop/document.pdf");` in the program, all goes well.  So why isn't the path getting sent to the filesInputStream from the command line?

Thanks.

```
package fileRead;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;

public class fileRead {

      public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

            InputStream is = null;
            try {
              is = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
              ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
              Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
              PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser();
              pdfparser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata, new ParseContext());

              PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/home/marek/Downloads/the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
              writer.println(contenthandler.toString());
              writer.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (is != null) is.close();
            }
          }

}
```

Comment: I think you're reading the file `fileRead`, not `document.pdf`. If your JAR has a main class in your manifest, it will be executed without you needing to specify it on the command line. Maybe you mixed it up with `java -cp fileRead.jar fileRead document.pdf`, where you do need to specify the main class? Try `java -jar fileRead.jar document.pdf`, or the abovementioned `-cp` variation. Also try printing `args[0]` to see for yourself what it is.

Comment: Steve - sorry for "rejecting" your edit.  It was a mistake, a good suggestion, i rejected it inadvertently. Sorry.

Comment: You are right Amadan.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer formally then:

`java -jar <jarname> <args...>` will invoke the main class of an executable JAR.

`java -cp <jarname> <classname> <args...>` will invoke the specified class of a JAR (not necessarily executable).

If you put the classname in the first syntax, it actually becomes the first parameter, so your `args` array is shifted by one position since a useless `fileRead` parameter enters the fray.